# What would happen when a material with Inhomogeneously broadened profile interacts with a light beam?

Tags: quantum-information

I have something which I am sure that I understand it correctly. Would you please told me if I explain this correctly or not. Sorry in advance for my English.

When a light beam interacts with an atoms of a material with an inhomogeneously broadened profile, an electron got excited and emits a photon. Because of the inhomogeneouly broadened profile, for every different frequency of the light beam, the material emits a photon with different linewidth.

Do I say it correctly?

Comment: That's pretty much it.   For light having any energy lying within the profile, there will be some atoms that will be able to absorb it.